# Is there a case when const data should be load in RAM rather then direct flash access

Tags: c, microcontroller, ram, flash-memory

I've used few types microcontrollers.
When I write code like this:

```
const int var = 5;
```

usually `var` is kept in flash. I understand that `const` variables are not always kept only in flash. Sometimes (depending compiler, processor, options like pic etc.) they are loaded from flash to RAM before `main`. Is there a case, when it is better to load `var` into RAM?

Comment: I cannot think of a case where this would matter. Of course assuming you do not write around in flash. May I know the context of that question? how did it arise in the first place?

Comment: Flash memories are more likely to have "wait states", in case the CPU is faster than the physical memory. But any form of memory could have that, including RAM or data cache.

Comment: I ask for personal curiosity. I understand that const variriables  are not alway keep only in flash. Sometimes( depending compiler, processor) theay are load from flash to ram before main.

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev Are you able to modify your linker script to test both cases?

Comment: yes changing rodata or set pic option

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev - were you able to do some kind of access testing under both scenarios. If so, can you post results?

Comment: @InfinitelyManic I was using compiler green hills on rh850 and  analyze disassembly. I sawthat in the first case the address of *var* was in RAM. in the other in ROM depending on wether I use pic option. But this is specific to compiler. It's gcc based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many microcontrollers have a unified address space, but some (such as AVRs) do not.  When there are multiple address spaces, then you may need to use different instructions to access data in those spaces.  (For AVR, the `LPM` (Load Program Memory) instruction must be used to access data in Flash, instead of one of the ordinary `LD` (Load) instructions.)

If you imagine a pointer to your `const` variable, a function receiving the pointer would not be able to access the data unless it knows which address space the pointer points into.  In a case like that, you either have to copy the data to RAM, even though it's `const`, or the user of the pointer has to know which instruction to use to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Microcontroller architecture like ARM Cortex or Microchip MIPS (and many others), RAM and Flash are mapped to different parts of the internal address space, like a huge array. So the Assembly commands reading from RAM are the same like reading from Flash. No difference here.

Access times of RAM and Flash shouldn't be too different, so no waiting needed on any of the controllers I've worked with.

The only case I can imagine where storing const vars in flash could cause problems is in some sort of bootloader app, when the flash is written. Of course, writing to a flash range where you are executing from is a bad idea and will cause much heavier problems than overwritten const values.